# In elasticsearch after adding a new field to a doc, cannot find with "exists" filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm adding a field to a doc like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/imap_email/imap_bruce/12/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.simperium = \"12345\""
}'
```

Looking at that doc, I can verify that it has added the field "simperium". The following query (and the many variations of it I've tried) simply return everything in my index.

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "exists" : { "field" : "simperium" }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get a strict list of all docs that do or don't have a specific field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of Elasitcsearch examples exclude the outer `"query" : {}` object for brevity. It's very annoying when starting out, but eventually you learn to accept it.

You most likely wanted this:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
      "filter" : {
        "exists" : { "field" : "simperium" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```